# Help with drawing quantum circuit

Tags: circuits, qcircuit

I was looking for a little help or direction to more examples of drawing quantum circuits using tikz similar to http://texample.net/tikz/examples/quantum-circuit/?

Starting with the above link i created the follow:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[hang,small,bf]{caption}    % fancy captions
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,decorations.pathreplacing}                  % TikZ libraries
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\ensuremath{\left|#1\right\rangle}} % Dirac Kets
%%%
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\begin{comment}
:Title: Quantum circuit
This code produces an image of a "quantum circuit" for addition modulus p of two n bit numbers using two ancillary qubits, one clean and set as zero, and one dirty. Both are returned to their initial state.
\end{comment}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centerline{
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\tikzstyle{operator} = [draw,fill=white,minimum size=1.5em] 
\tikzstyle{phase} = [fill,shape=circle,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{surround} = [fill=blue!10,thick,draw=black,rounded corners=2mm]
%
% Qubits
\node at (0,0) (q0)  {\ket{x^n}};
\node at (0,-1) (q1) {\ket{y^n}};
\node at (0,-2) (q2) {\ket{0}};
\node at (0,-3) (q3) {\ket{g}};
\node at (0,-4) (q4) {\ket{\tt ctrl}};
%
% Column 1
\node[operator] (op1-0) at (1,0) {$+$} edge [-] (q0);
\node[operator] (op1-1) at (1,-1) {$+$} edge [-] (q1);
\node[operator] (op1-2) at (1,-2) {$+$} edge [-] (q2);
\draw[-] (op1-1) -- (op1-2);
\draw[-] (op1-0) -- (op1-1);
%
% Column 2
\node[operator] (op2-1) at (2,-1) {$-p$} edge [-] (op1-1);
\node[operator] (op2-2) at (2,-2) {$-p$} edge [-] (op1-2);
\node[operator] (op2-3) at (2,-3) {$-p$} edge [-] (q3);
\draw[-] (op2-1) -- (op2-2);
\draw[-] (op2-2) -- (op2-3);
%
% Column 3
\node[operator] (op3-1) at (3,-1) {$+p$} edge [-] (op2-1);
\node[phase] (ph3-2) at (3,-2) {} edge [-] (op2-2);
\node[operator] (op3-3) at (3,-3) {$+p$} edge [-] (op2-3);
\draw[-] (op3-1) -- (ph3-2);
\draw[-] (ph3-2) -- (op3-3);
%
% Column 4
\node[operator] (op4-0) at (4,0) {$>$} edge [-] (op1-0);
\node[operator] (op4-1) at (4,-1) {$>$} edge [-] (op3-1);
\node[operator] (op4-2) at (4,-2) {$>$} edge [-] (ph3-2);
\draw[-] (op4-1) -- (op4-2);
\draw[-] (op4-0) -- (op4-1);
%
% Column 5
\node[operator] (op5-2) at (5,-2) {$\oplus$} edge [-] (op4-2);
%
% Column 6
\node (end1) at (6,0)  {\ket{x^n}} edge [-] (op4-0);
\node (end1) at (6,-1) {\ket{(x+y)^n}} edge [-] (op4-1);
\node (end1) at (6,-2) {\ket{0}} edge [-] (op5-2);
\node (end2) at (6,-3) {\ket{g}} edge [-] (op3-3);
\node (end3) at (6,-4) {\ket{{\tt ctrl}}} edge [-] (q4);
\end{tikzpicture}
 }
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}}
```

[image]
But I want the boxes to cover two or three qubits at once not separate boxes. Such that the first column is one rectangle covering the first three qubits. Is this possible? Id also like to remove the box at the end around the |0> qubit too if you have suggestions for this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm wrong or at the end of your document you have two `}}` see `\end{document}}`.

Comment: If you search here for `quantum circuit` you might find better examples.